# image corrupt while Uploading image to Digital Ocean spaces, after accepting using html form

Tags: python, html, forms, file-upload, digital-ocean

Step 1: I am accepting image (.JPEG) using HTML form

```
<input id="myFileInput" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="readURL(this);" autocomplete="off" required style="width: 100%">
```

Step 2: in backend Python: I am received image object as below

```
file = request.files['file'] #JPEG image file
```

Step 3: Now I want to upload this image (.JPEG image object) to Digital Ocean space - while the file is getting uploaded successfully, I am not able to open and view the image. Looks like it is getting corrupt along the way.

Digital ocean file upload procedure

```
from boto3 import session

ACCESS_ID = zzzzzzzzzzz
SECRET_KEY = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
session = session.Session()
client = session.client('s3',
                        region_name='sgp1',
                        endpoint_url='https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
                        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

#Upload a file to your digital ocean Space:
client.upload_fileobj(file, 'DO_Bucket', 
                     'DO_path' + filename,
                     ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

Other option tried: It works when I save the file locally and then upload it to DO-Spaces

```
client.upload_file('file_path' + filename, 'DO_Bucket', 
                   'DO_path' + filename, 
                    ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

Expected output: I should be able to upload the image object directly without any need to save it locally

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the CDN? After enabling the CDN you would also need to mention it in the middleware file of your project.
something like:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => [
  ...,
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
          'script-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'cdn.jsdelivr.net'],
          'img-src': [
            "'self'",
            'data:',
            'cdn.jsdelivr.net',
            'strapi.io',
            'dl.airtable.com',
            '<bucket>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com',
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  ...
];
```

Also may be try writing files in caps, so it should be :
file = request.FILES['file'] #JPEG image file

You can check [this wpengine documentation page](https://wpengine.com/support/how-does-a-cdn-work/#:%7E:text=modern%20CDN%20here.-,Enable%20CDN,secured%20with%20no%20additional%20steps.) to learn how to enable CDN.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not enabled CDN. I also tried with capital FILES. Its throws error as 'Request' object has no attribute 'FILES'

Comment: Try enabling the CDN. You can refer the documentation for it.